# How to use BaggingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I don't understand how to use the `BaggingClassifier` from sklearn.
Let's say I have a dataframe of inputs of shape (10,5) and a dataframe of targets of shape (10,1):

```
traininginputs:

              Date         A             B     
       2015-01-02          5             1     
       2015-01-02          6             2     
       2015-01-02          4             3     
       2015-01-02          1             2     
       2015-01-02          3             2    
       2015-01-03          1             1   

trainingtarget:
            Date           t         
       2015-01-02          1          
       2015-01-02         -1               
       2015-01-02          1               
       2015-01-02          1                
       2015-01-02          1              
       2015-01-03         -1
```

If I do the following:

```
clf1 = svm.SVC( probability=True)
model = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=clf1)
model.fit(traininginputs.values, trainingtarget.values)
model.predict(testinputs)
```

with

testinputs:

```
          Date         A             B     
   2015-01-02          5             1     
   2015-01-02          6             2     
   2015-01-02          4             3     
   2015-01-02          1             2     
   2015-01-02          3             2    
   2015-01-03          1             1
```

Why doesn't it work ?
I feel like I am missing something about the way to use `BaggingClassifier`

Comment: Your question is very What is the problem? Are you getting any error? Are the predictions not right?

Answer (score 0):

In `fit()`, y needs to be a 1d vector, but training_target.values will return a column vector. You can transform it using `ravel()`:

```
model.fit(training_inputs.values, training_target.values.ravel())
```

Comment: I am unsure about your answer because I tried to fit other models (SVC, MLPClassifier etc) and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work then? Can you add your error message to the question?

Comment: No, mostly column vectors will be fine (sometimes a warning).